# Build caffe with Python ( cannot find -lboost_python3 )

Tags: python, boost, caffe

I'm trying to build caffe with python but it keep saying this

```
CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [python/caffe/_caffe.so] Error 1
```

This is what I get when I try to locate `boost_python`

```
$ sudo locate boost_python
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.55.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py33.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py33.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py33.so.1.55.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so
```

I've add this path also

```
## .bashrc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Any idea why is that happing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the problem. it turned out that it tries to look for something with that name of `libboost_python3.so` after changing the name in Makefile.config from `boost_python3` to `boost_python-py34`, it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old, but :

```
dnf install boost-python3-devel
```

may help !

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to build Caffe and faced the same issue. Unfortunately, none of the answers work in my case. I checked the location of lboost_python by the following command:

 `find /usr/lib -name libboost_python-py`

I found the lboost_python libraries and here are some of them:

- libboost_python37.a
- libboost_python37-mt.a
- libboost_python37-mt.so
- libboost_python37-mt.so.1.68.0

Then in the **Makefile.config** file I changed the following line: 
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := **boost_python** python3.7m   
to 
PYTHON_LIBRARIES := **boost_python37-mt** python3.7m