# PyCaffe build fails, lboost_python not found

Tags: python, macos, caffe, boost-python

I am on MacOS 10.13.3 (17D47) with Python 2.7.14. I am in the process of building caffe w/ python. The project is CPU only. I am able to build caffe through `make run test` however, after attempting `make pycaffe` I get an error. This is the result:

```
touch python/caffe/proto/__init__.py
CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
PROTOC (python) src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
In file included from python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:17:
In file included from ./include/caffe/caffe.hpp:12:
./include/caffe/net.hpp:41:5: warning: unused typedef 'INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
    LOG_EVERY_N(WARNING, 1000) << "DEPRECATED: ForwardPrefilled() "
    ^
/usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:943:30: note: expanded from macro 'LOG_EVERY_N'
                             INVALID_REQUESTED_LOG_SEVERITY);           \
                             ^
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lboost_python
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [python/caffe/_caffe.so] Error 1
```

I have a Makefile.config that calls out boost-python from the brew install set as:

```
# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.67.0/lib
```

My two initial questions are: 
1)Am I not allowed to link to the boost library using the system python? 2)What is the correct way to tell make to grab boost-python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was actually having the same problem and couldn't find any answers for days.  However, I found this question: [Build caffe with Python ( cannot find -lboost_python3 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616527/build-caffe-with-python-cannot-find-lboost-python3) .

That question is for python3, but I'm using python2.7 .  Basically, I went into the Makefile (not Makefile.config), searched for `boost_python`, and changed it to `boost_python27` .  I did the following steps:

1. `vim Makefile`
2. `use vim command :?boost_python` (there should only be 1 occurrence)
3. `changed PYTHON_LIBRARIES ?= boost_python python2.7
         to PYTHON_LIBRARIES ?= boost_python27 python2.7`
4. ran the command `sudo make pycaffe`

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

Goto Makefile (and not the .config file) and change the name of the ld library to python27.

Comment: In Makefile I have: PYTHON_LIBRARIES ?= boost_python python2.7  Should I remove the '.' ? Thank you for your knowledge.

Comment: This is my config of Python_Libraries that worked for me : 

PYTHON_LIBRARIES ?= boost_python27 python2.7